# How to store php array to text

Tags: php, arrays, string

i have php array like this.

```
$config['sample'] = array( 'key1' => 'val1', 'key2' => 'val2' );
```

and i want value in $config['sample'] to write in to **text** file like this.

> $newcfg['sample'] = array( 'key1' => 'val1', 'key2' => 'val2' );

How to convert from php array value to text string before write to text file?

ps. 1. I cannot use serialize because when i write to a file, it must be ready to use in php as same as $config['sample'] value.

ps. 2. I cannot use json encode/decode also. same reason as i cannot use serialize.

use **var_export** really works. thanks to **@fr4nk**

Comment: Perhaps you should have a look at `serialize` and `unserialize` instead

Comment: Maybe `var_export` is an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `var_export`. It exports a variable into executable PHP code. You then write that into a text file.

Answer (score 1):

couple of options

```
$version1=print_r($config['sample'],1);
$version2=serialize($config['sample']);
```

[serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) is better if you want to be able to get the array structure back

Answer (score 0):

you could encode your array to [JSON](http://www.json.org/) before writing it to a file like:

```
file_put_contents('myfile.json', json_encode( $myArray ));
```

then decode it back afterwards:

```
$myArray = json_decode( file_get_contents('myfile.json') );
```

see:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

What about the implode function?

```
$mystring = implode(" ", $myarray);
```